# Cisco management VLAN -- switchport configuration

Tags: cisco

Does assigning a switchport to the management interface sacrifice that port? That is to say, do I lose the ability to plug a device into that port and assign it another VLAN? 
If I take a brand new C2960 and do this:

```
Switch(config)#int vlan 99  
Switch(config-if)#ip address 172.17.99.11 255.255.255.0  
Switch(config)#int fa0/24  
Switch(config-if)#switchport mode access   
Switch(config-if)#switchport access vlan 99
```

- Does VLAN 1 cease to be the native VLAN as soon as I create this management VLAN and assign an IP to it?
- Can I no longer plug, say, a PC into port 24 and put it in VLAN 30?

I can't wrap my head around the management interface concept.

Thank you.

Comment: Keep in mind: The management VLAN is a concept. It is conceptual. It's not a "real" entity. It's nothing more than a VLAN that you create in order to configure an SVI with an ip address in order to manage the switch. It has no relevance to the operation of the switch and has no bearing on the native/default VLAN. A "management" VLAN is a VLAN just like any other VLAN and functions as such from the switch's perspective. Your use of it is what makes it a "management" VLAN. The reason for creating a "management" VLAN is to separate management traffic from user traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The management VLAN, for all intents and purposes, is a logical construct and is specific to your configuration. Your management VLAN doesn't have any commonality with my management VLAN other than the fact that they both have an SVI with an ip address assigned to it. You can create a management VLAN from any VLAN you like because at the end of the day the management VLAN is nothing more than an SVI that you assign an ip address to for the purpose of managing the switch.

If you assign a port to the management VLAN then you cannot assign that port to another VLAN as a port may be a member of only one VLAN, but this doesn't have anything to do with whether or not you're using that VLAN as a management VLAN. If you connect a host to a port that is a member of your management VLAN than that host will only communicate with other hosts in the same VLAN, but this has nothing to do with whether you consider this VLAN a management VLAN or not. The fact that you're using this VLAN as your management VLAN is irrelevant to the switch. The "management" VLAN is a construct of your management needs. The switch doesn't know one VLAN from another in terms of what the VLAN is used for.

The native VLAN isn't affected by creating a management VLAN and the native VLAN is only relevant to trunk ports (AFAIK). Traffic on the native VLAN isn't tagged and as such will transit the trunk link untagged and will be delivered to switch ports that have membership in the native (default-untagged) VLAN. Again, the native/default VLAN isn't relevant to what VLAN you use as your management VLAN. The management VLAN is nothing more than an SVI with an ip address that you use to manage the switch.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  I think you are mixing up a vlan and vlan interface.  In your example, interface fa0/24 will only be assigned to vlan99 and will require an IP address in the 172.17.99.x IP range.  In order to route to another vlan or subnet, you will need to a second interface configured on vlan99 (access port or trunk port would work) that will connect to a layer 3 routing server.

Does that clarify the idea any further?

Reference the CCNA workbook...
http://www.freeccnaworkbook.com/workbooks/ccna/configuring-a-management-vlan-interface

Comment: Thank you for the link. I will definitely check out that site.